Warning: Unknown token: monitor
When starting my snmp daemon the following error is thrown:
**snmpd -LOw -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -f
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 10: Warning: Unknown token: monitor.
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 11: Warning: Unknown token: defaultMonitor.
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 12: Warning: Unknown token: linkUpDownNotifications.**

According to my extensive research, this is apparently due to the lack of DisMan Event support in the SNMP binary. However, support should actually have been recompiled as standard since version 5.4. This can also be easily found out using the command "net-snmp-config --configure-options". The output of this command is attached. However, only the following line is actually important:
--with-mib-modules=smux ucd-snmp/dlmod mibII/mta_sendmail disman/event-mib ucd-snmp/diskio ucd-snmp/lmsensorsMib etherlike-mib/dot3StatsTable host

This line should actually guarantee that the support is compiled in. If you are interested in my snmpd.conf, it is also attached. I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct syntax as it comes directly from the man page for snmpd.
 '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-option-checking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--with-persistent-directory=/var/lib/snmp' '--enable-ucd-snmp-compatibility' '--with-cflags=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/net-snmp-m72y6Y/net-snmp-5.9.1+dfsg=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DNETSNMP_USE_INLINE' '--with-ldflags=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' '--with-perl-modules=INSTALLDIRS=vendor' '--enable-as-needed' '--with-logfile=none' '--without-rpm' '--with-libwrap' '--with-openssl' '--without-dmalloc' '--without-efence' '--without-rsaref' '--with-sys-contact=root' '--with-sys-location=Unknown' '--with-mib-modules=smux ucd-snmp/dlmod mibII/mta_sendmail disman/event-mib ucd-snmp/diskio ucd-snmp/lmsensorsMib etherlike-mib/dot3StatsTable host' '--with-out-mib-modules=' '--with-transports=TLSTCP DTLSUDP' '--with-security-modules=tsm' '--enable-mfd-rewrites' '--with-mnttab=/etc/mtab' '--with-mibdirs=/home/paul/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf' '--with-mysql' '--with-systemd' '--enable-blumenthal-aes' 'UNAMEPROG=/bin/uname' 'PSPROG=/bin/ps' '--with-defaults' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/net-snmp-m72y6Y/net-snmp-5.9.1+dfsg=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'


To anybody seeing this and having this problem. The solution was to edit the starting command for the daemon with
sudo systemctl edit --full snmpd
and remove the mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf from the the starting command so it looks like this
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -LOw -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux -f
You also need to add Enviroment Variables MIBDIRS and MIBS like this
Environment="MIBSDIR=/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/u>
Environment="MIBS=UCD-SNMP-MIB:HOST-RESOURCES-MIB"

I dont know if this is supposed to be like this because I have never seen anybody removing mteTrigger and mteTriggerConf from the exclusion but this seems to work. I am now able to monitor my desired OIDs and traps are being generated.
And for people wondering, the -I option excludes the following list from being loaded when its started with '-'.
